# How to create a new instance of anonymous class in Java

Tags: java

I tried to create a object from anonymous class in run time.but when i tried to call `newInstance()` it throw an error called `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

**Anonymous Class Implementation**

```
public enum Delegates implements Supplier<User> {

ADMINUSER {
        @Override
        public User get() {
            return  new User(){

                @Override
                public String getRole() {

                    return "Admin";
                }

            };


        }
}
```

**User.Java**

```
public class User{

public String getRole() {
    return "Student";
}
}
```

**Create Instance from Runtime**

```
Delegates.ADMINUSER.get().getClass().newInstance()
```

**throw an error called**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.users.Delegates$4$1.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Please let me know how to create a instance from anonymous class in run time.

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance, just use your get method:

```
User user = Delegates.ADMINUSER.get();
```